# использование скрипта Jquery datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Использую Jquery datepicker на одной странице для нескольких полей,но почему то открывает только в одно месте (в  первом поле) , в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: может быть у тебя стоит для всех элементов полей одинаковый `id`?

Comment: Конечно скорее всего у вас у пикеров одинаковый айдишник, а не класс, но лучше бы вы код добавили, чтоб не пришлось обращаться к звездам и танцевать с бубном